# Once conjunction for future events in the past

Tags: tense, conjunctions, future-in-the-past

Say I have a first-person past-tense narration of a character. This character is narrating a scene where they're about to eat candy and thus will need to brush their teeth, but this event is occurring *before* the state of narration. If I would like to begin this sentence with the conjunction "once," what kind of tense would be required?

> Once I ***ate*** the candy, I would need to brush my teeth.

> Once I ***would eat*** the candy, I would need to brush my teeth.

> Something else entirely.

Comment: What has your research told you about the grammar of using "once" as a conjunction?

Comment: I would call *"once"* a Preposition and use the first sentence. I don't think the second one is correct.